# How to wait for a task to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

The problem is with the output

The current output is

> job waiting
>
> job starting
>
> Delay started
>
> job done
>
> Delay ended

Where as I wanted to be

> job waiting
>
> job starting
>
> Delay started
>
> Delay ended
>
> job done

```
    private static Task _task;

    public static  void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Call().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task Call()
    {
        _task = new Task(async () => { await Pause(); });
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("job waiting");
        await _task;
        Console.WriteLine("job done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task Pause()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delay started");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Delay ended");

    }
    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("job starting");

        _task.Start();

    }
```

Comment: The `Task` constructor is not meant to be passed async tasks, and you don't even need to. `_task = new Task(() => Pause());`

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. There's seldom any reason to use the `Task` constructor. *All* examples, tutorials, classes, articles show using `Task.Run` (or `Task.Factory.StartNew` before 2012) to start a new task.

Comment: If you want to await for `Pause` you can just write `await Pause()` in `Call()`. `Task.Delay()` doesn't block, so there's no reason to start that in another thread. Using `await Task.Run(()=>Pause())` means that the `Console.WriteLine` statements will run in a background thread, `Task.Delay` will work the same way it did before

Comment: Hi I appreciate all the answers above but the reason I did this way because I need to create a task at a certain point of time but start it later, So you see it is then necessary for me to create a task via constructor \

Comment: Tasks are normally created in a "hot" state, meaning they are already started. As far as I know cold tasks are not working well with `await`. Would it be possible instead of creating a cold task, to create instead a delegate, and use later this delegate as an action for a hot task?

Answer (score 1):

> the reason I did this way because I need to create a task at a certain point of time but start it later

The appropriate tool in this case is `Func<Task>`, not the `Task` constructor. [The `Task` constructor should never, ever be used](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

In this case, your output is not as desired because the `Task` constructor does not understand `async` delegates. So the `async` delegate passed to the `Task` constructor is treated as `async void`, which makes awaiting on it infeasible.

The fix is to use `async`-aware tools. In this case, an [async-compatible delegate](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). Since the `Task` object doesn't exist until the timer event fires, you also need to pass that object to the other method as a "signal", which is somewhat awkward. Most real-world code does not need to do this:

```
private static Func<Task> _func;
private static TaskCompletionSource<Task> _taskSignal = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();
private static async Task Call()
{
  _func = Pause;
  var timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = 10000;
  timer.Enabled = true;
  timer.AutoReset = false;
  timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
  Console.WriteLine("job waiting");
  var task = await _taskSignal.Task; // Get the Task instance representing Pause
  await task; // Wait for Pause to finish
  Console.WriteLine("job done");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task Pause()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Delay started");
  await Task.Delay(10000);
  Console.WriteLine("Delay ended");
}

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("job starting");
  var task = _func(); // Start Pause running
  _taskSignal.TrySetResult(task); // Pass the Pause task back to Main
}
```

Comment: The [link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) doesn't really explain why the `Task` constructor should never be used. It explains why it's not usually needed. But if someone wants for whatever reason to `await` a cold task, what bad things could happen?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: The only use case for the `Task` constructor is for cold delegate tasks, which were not a good idea 9 years ago and have been ignored ever since. `Action` and `Func<Task>` were better choices 9 years ago and they still are today. If you `await` a cold task, the `await` never completes.

Comment: I tested the case of awaiting cold tasks, and the `await` do completes, provided that the task is started meanwhile by a timer or some other task. So the disadvantage of awaiting cold tasks must be something else.

Comment: If you start the cold task, it's not cold anymore.

Comment: Cold [are called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status) the tasks that begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled Created state. Not the tasks that remain non-scheduled forever!

Comment: These are called frozen. 

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to make the body of the task synchronous. In other words instead of this:

```
_task = new Task(async () => { await Pause(); });
```

...do this:

```
_task = new Task(() => { Pause().Wait(); });
```

If you want to keep it asynchronous then you must find a way to await the body of the task. This can be achieved by creating a `Task<Task>`, and awaiting the result of the task instead of the main task itself:

```
_task = new Task<Task>(async () => { await Pause(); });
//...
await _task.Result;
```